# Angular datatable as a component

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-datatables

I am using Datatable for Angular and using it in a template like this :

```
<manager-table [data]="items" [columns]="columns" [loading]="isLoading" ></manager-table>
```

and in the `table.component.ts` I have

```
@Component({
    selector: "manager-table",
    templateUrl: "./table.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./table.component.scss"],
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

    public dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
    public dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    public _data: Array<any>;
    public _columns: any;

    @ViewChild(DataTableDirective, { static: false }) private datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

     @Input()
    
        set data(data: any) {
            if (data) {
                this._data = data;
                this.rerender();
            }
        }
    
        get data(): any {
            return this._data;
        }
```

and passing this data to the table and in the table I loop through the data.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of _data">
```

I am getting the data. But the problem is, it is not showing the pagination and the sort functionality is not working. I have a `rerender()` and it has following code.

```
rerender() {
        this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
            dtInstance.destroy();
            this.dtTrigger.next();
        });
    }
```

But this is also not working. Sometimes it will show the pagination, but sometimes not. How can I add the datatable to a component and use it in all the templates ?

Answer (score 0):

I must suppose you use your variable "isLoading" in a *ngIf. So, while the variable is true, you has no the table. You need check (using a setter like you make with the data) and is is true, make the `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` enclosed in a setTimeout

```
@Input set loading(value)
{
    this._loading=value;
    if (value)
    {
        setTimeout(()=>{
             this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
        })
    }
}
```

Brief explanaxion: In angular in a cycle first execute the code and then refresh the view (html). use a setTimeout say to Angular: eh!, you execute the code but, after refresh the view, execute this last instruction

See a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aunynt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-table.component.ts)